# Visual Studio Code terminal displaying "sh-3.2$" every time I "Open in Integrated Terminal" instead of the working directory name (Mac OS)

Tags: visual-studio-code

Earlier today I was having an issue where when I would go to open a new terminal or open a file or folder in Integrated Terminal the terminal would be automatically killed within a couple of seconds without me manually killing it. I was confused as to why this was happening because as far as I could tell I hadn't changed my settings.json file in VS Code or User or Workspace settings and everything was running smoothly just minutes earlier. I was able to resolve that issue but I created a new minor inconvenience. Now whenever I open a file or folder in Integrated terminal it displays "sh-3.2$" instead of the current directory I'm in. If I type pwd and press enter it'll of course display the current directory I'm in but I don't want to have to type that a million times moving forward. If somebody could help me fix this issue I'd greatly appreciate it! I read some of the documentation online but I'm a new bootcamp student and I tried following along but it was going over my head. Thanks again!

I was reading a similar Stack Overflow question and they were saying to try and setup/configure my bash shell to have a prompt with path, specifically the PS1 environment variable, but I was confused on how to actually go about doing that.

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem I went into terminal settings and switched from /bin/sh to /bin/zsh, fixed the issue for me

Answer (score 2):

In the terminal settings GUI, changing my terminal app solved it for me. As of today, you can reach this by opening the command palette (CMD+SHIFT+P) and selecting `Terminal: Configure Terminal Settings`.

Then change Terminal > External > Osx Exec. Put in the name of your terminal app of choice where your bash profile of choice is working. E.g. `iTerm.app` -- you can find this for other terminals through Finder/Apps, or right click the app in your dock and show in finder.

[image: How to find the name of your terminal app]

[image: VS Code command palette option for editing terminal settings]

[[image: Screenshot of terminal>external>osx exec option in VS code1]

Comment: Doing the above, then I had to restart VSCode to return the terminal to normal.